# Issue in adding buddy using asmack android

Tags: android, asmack

I have an issue with accepting buddy request using asmack android.

I am using the below given block of code to get the incoming buddy request.

```
connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
    public void processPacket(Packet packet) {  
        final Presence newPresence = (Presence) packet;
    final Presence.Type presenceType = newPresence.getType();
        if (presenceType == Presence.Type.subscribe) {
            //Code to add buddy here
        }
    }
}
```

This is working fine when the user is online. But the issue is when the user gets logged out. Suppose the user is logged out and at that time another user sends a buddy request. But when the user is logged in this method is not working.

Can anybody suggest a method to get the buddy request that the user gets when he/she is logged out of the application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi for recieving buddy request add following listener:Working perfectly for me

```
connection.getRoster().addRosterListener(rosterListener);
RosterListner rosterListner = new RosterListener(){


                @Override
                public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> clctn) {
                    System.out.println("Somebody added you");

                    for (String name : clctn) {
                        System.out.println("Somebody added you");
                        System.out.println("NAME:" + name);

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> clctn) {
                    System.out.println("Somebody Updated you");

                    for (String name : clctn) {
                        System.out.println("NAME:" + name);

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> clctn) {
                    System.out.println("Somebody Deleted you");

                    for (String name : clctn) {
                        System.out.println("NAME:" + name);

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void presenceChanged(Presence prsnc) {
                    System.out.println("Somebody changed Presence");
                    //insert status msg and profile pic here into db

                }
            };
```